# Hibernate JPA cascade types

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have read the cascade type definitions multiple times but i just cannot get my head around which one to use for the particular case i am trying to implement.

I have `@OneToMany` relationship between the `Worker` class and `Task` class, so `worker` can have multiple tasks but each `Task` is only for one `Worker`

`private List <Task> tasks` holds the tasks in the `Worker` class and
`private Worker worker;` is the `Worker` object in the `Task` class

I am stuck at the `?` below, don't know which cascade type i should use.

`@OneToMany(targetEntity=Task.class, mappedBy="worker", cascade=CascadeType.?, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`

Both objects should exist without one another but i want the changes to `Task` objects to reflect on the `Worker` object and vice versa

Ultimately(if i can get this to work :) ) i am suppose to write an algorithm to match the best worker when a new task get entered to the system i want to know if i am on the right track or not. Thanks

Comment: "Both objects should exist without one another but i want the changes to Task objects to reflect on the Worker object and vice versa" <- Can you specify what exactly you mean by that? Do you mean that if you modify "Task-A" that the Worker object linked to that should not link to an old version of "Task-A"? If that is all you are converned about then you don't need a CascadeType at all (NONE).

Comment: I recommend you `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` and add `deleteOrphan=true`. But be careful if you use JPA 2/2.1 + Hibernate 5, the cascade delete isn't well managed, I recommend you to do the cascade delete manually.

Comment: @Zorglube it's `orphanRemoval` and not `deleteOrphan` and if he uses it, it will delete the elements that are not in a relation with the other side, and that's not what he is looking for.

Comment: Thank you @chsdk  for correcting me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well in your specific case you want to revert changes in one entity to the other side and you don't want to remove it if the mapping entity is removed, to answer both your requirements:

> Both objects should exist without one another

In that case you should not use `CascadeType.REMOVE` type because it *emoves all related entities association with this setting when the owning entity is deleted.*

> but i want the changes to `Task` objects to reflect on the  `Worker`

In that case using the `CascadeType.PERSIST` and `CascadeType.MERGE` types will be sufficient to reflect changes between both sides as `CascadeType.PERSIST` covers both `save()` and `persist()` operations while `CascadeType.MERGE` will handle the `merge()` operation.

For further details about this topic I suggest reading [HowToDoInJava **Hibernate JPA Cascade Types** article](http://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/hibernate-jpa-cascade-types/) as it briefly illustartes all these cases.

Comment: Thank you this makes sense to me now.

Comment: beware the linked articlel above blithely conflates the concept of `relationship owner` and `parent`

Comment: I can't see how it's confusing, it only uses the `owner` and `relationship` terms to illustrate that.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on how you are using your entities.

- If you never detach your entities, then you don't need `CascadeType.DETACH`. If you do, then you should probably include this `CascadeType`.
- When you merge your detached worker back into your persistence context, do you also want its tasks merged? This is not an easy decision, but from what you're saying you probably don't modify a worker and a task in the same process, so you probably don't want this.
- `CascadeType.PERSIST` is usually a good choice and you can't really go wrong with this one. But like above: It doesn't sound like you are creating a worker and a new task in the same process. But if you do, then choose this `CascadeType`.
- You definitely don't want to use `CascadeType.REMOVE` from what I understand.